# Get reference to target which is other element

Tags: html, angular

I need to collapse other component from a button. So I have a directive name `collapse` and I want to set target collapseme to the diretive.

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a [collapse]="isColapse" [collapseTarget]="collapseme" (click)="isColapse= !isColapse">
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseme">
      <div class="panel-body">
        collapse content
      </div>
    </div>
```

But I cant find solution for it. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Explained the best here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: share the plunkr link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a template variable `#collapseme`

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a [collapse]="isColapse" [collapseTarget]="collapseme" (click)="isColapse= !isColapse">
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseme" #collapseme> <!-- modified -->
  <div class="panel-body">
    collapse content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I need it in for loop. so I will change from #collapseme to some kind of #collapseme{{index}} to make them unique targets. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: `#collapseme{{index}}` won't work. This might work `@ViewChildren('collapseme', {read: ElementRef}) collapsmes:QueryList<ElementRef>; and `[collapseTarget]="collspsemes.toArray()[index]". There might be an easier way but I'd need more details. Have you actually tried if the code in my answer still works with `*ngFor`? (with all `id="collapseme"` have the same `#collapseme` template variable?

Comment: If the element where you add the template variable and where you use it are within `<tag *ngFor>...</tag>` the created tags each have their own scope and multiple instances of the same template variable don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Your first solution using `@ViewChildren` is working very well for the situation that I may have them in two for loop instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used bootstrap. You can do it via bootstrap
[collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: it is not good to use bootstrap jquery inside of angular2. that's why I use only css and handle thing by typescript.

Comment: You can check following link for this https://embed.plnkr.co/oVoPIA0ZbMMauth812Ls/